# Attributes order rule in Nuxt3?

Tags: nuxtjs3

Previously, when using Nuxt2, there were validation checks for the order of the attributes in the templates.

Running a Nuxt3 project, it seems to no longer be the case by default.

How could I enable it back? I couldn't find a solution online.